# How to config the default language of a class library

Tags: win-universal-app

For an Windows app, the option for the default language is found in `Package.appxmanifest` under the project. However, I do not know where to find the setting for a class library, because there is nothing like `Package.appxmanifest` under a class library project.

As a result, after I add `Strings\zh-CN\Resources.resw` and a few strings into a class library project, I get a few warnings, saying:

> MakePRI : warning 0xdef00522: Resources found for language(s) 'zh-cn' but no resources found for default language(s): 'en-US'. Change the default language or qualify resources with the default language. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=231899
>
> MakePRI : warning 0xdef01051: No default or neutral resource given for '...'. The application may throw an exception for certain user configurations when retrieving the resources.

<sub>No actual help from "fwlink" as usual.</sub>

Although nothing bad actually happens because the app gets zh-CN as its default language, it is still quite annoying and I would like to eliminate the warnings to turn on "treat warnings as errors".

Comment: @JaydenGu Thanks, but this does not get rid of the warnings in the compilation.

Comment: I have the same problem in the app itself even if the language in the `Package.appxmanifest` is correctly set

Comment: this is really annoying... I can't get rid of this warning. @DanteisnotaGeek did you still have the warning?

Comment: @letiagoalves Sad but yes.

Comment: so I got rid of this warning by adding a 'en-us' folder and copying all of my resources there. not trying to figure out how to change the default language, so I don't have to maintain multiple folders...

Answer (score 2):

Try to manually edit the `<DefaultLanguage>` in the `csproj` file. It's under the first `<PropertyGroup>` subtree.

Here is a snippet of the context where you should be able to find this tag:

```
<DefaultLanguage>zh-CN</DefaultLanguage>
<TargetPlatformIdentifier>UAP</TargetPlatformIdentifier>
<TargetPlatformVersion>10.0.10240.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
<TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.10240.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
<MinimumVisualStudioVersion>14</MinimumVisualStudioVersion>
```